# Could not load exp://...:19000 in android studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, expo, expo-go

When running expo start the app is compiled and working but when pressing 'a' to start it in the android emulator it fails to load the app.

I tried removing .expo folder and let 'expo start' recreate it and I checked if they are using the same subnetwork which I think should not even be the case because I am starting both expo server and android emulator in the same machine.

Expo version: 33.0.0. Expo cli version: 3.4.1. React version: 16.8.6. React Native version 0.59.8.

Thank you.

Please find the images below for more details and let me know if you need any other detail provided:

[Error Message after pressing 'a' to run the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoOrN.png)

[Setting.json file in .expo folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwn3l.png)

[packager-info.json file in .expo folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG1cJ.png)